# How to save / serialize a trained model in theano?

Tags: python, serialization, save, loading, theano

I saved the model as documented on [loading and saving](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loading_and_saving.html).

```
# saving trained model
f = file('models/simple_model.save', 'wb')
cPickle.dump(ca, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
f.close()
```

`ca` is a trained auto-encoder. It's a instance of class [`cA`](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/cA.py). From the script in which I build and save the model I can call `ca.get_reconstructed_input(...)` and `ca.get_hidden_values(...)` without any problem.

In a different script I try to load the trained model.

```
# loading the trained model
model_file = file('models/simple_model.save', 'rb')
ca = cPickle.load(model_file)
model_file.close()
```

I receive the following error.

> ```
> ca = cPickle.load(model_file)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cA'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the class definitions of the pickled objects need to be known by the script that does the unpickling. There is more on this in other StackOverflow questions (e.g. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'newperson'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127714/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-newperson)).

Your code is correct as long as you properly import `cA`. Given the error you're getting it may not be the case. Make sure you're using `from cA import cA` and not just `import cA`.

Alternatively, your model is defined by its parameters so you could instead just pickle the parameter values). This could be done in two ways depending on what you point of view.

1. Save the Theano shared variables. Here we assume that `ca.params` is a regular Python list of Theano shared variable instances.

   ```
   cPickle.dump(ca.params, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   ```
2. Save the numpy arrays stored inside the Theano shared variables.

   ```
   cPickle.dump([param.get_value() for param in ca.params], f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   ```

When you want to load the model you'll need to reinitialize the parameters. For example, create a new instance of the `cA` class then either

```
ca.params = cPickle.load(f)
ca.W, ca.b, ca.b_prime = ca.params
```

or

```
ca.params = [theano.shared(param) for param in cPickle.load(f)]
ca.W, ca.b, ca.b_prime = ca.params
```

Note that you need to set both the `params` field and the separate parameters fields.

Comment: The error I'm seeing is due to the fact that I was using `import cA` instead of `from cA import cA`. The code I posted is otherwise correct.

Your alternatives are correct as well.

I think the cleanest way to close this thread is for you to add something in your first paragraph (which identifies the real source of the problem) like "make sure you're using `from cA import cA` and not just `import cA`", and I could mark your answer as accepted.

Thanks!

Comment: For me, loading a model from cpickle is about as slow as compiling it.

Comment: As far as I understood, it is very important to know that this pickle file will essentially be bound to the same hardware, at least you can not load a cuda-based model on a cpu-based Theano. I was very surprised by the fact that it is a non-trivial task to transfer the learned networks between different hardwares.

Comment: The learned network need be nothing more then the trained parameters. You do not need to pickle the compiled Theano function. Indeed it may be better to avoid that for the reason you give. It can be preferable to simply pickle the model parameters (as numpy arrays, not Theano shared variables) then load those back into whichever form of the network is compiled (i.e. either CPU or GPU version).

Comment: @DanielRenshaw it should be possible to use `theano.misc.pkl_utils.dump()` and `theano.misc.pkl_utils.load()` to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way to save model is to save its weights and architecture and then load the same, the way we do for pre-train CNN:

```
def save_model(model):


   model_json = model.to_json()
   open('cifar10_architecture.json', 'w').write(model_json)
   model.save_weights('cifar10_weights.h5', overwrite=True)
```

source/ref : https://blog.rescale.com/neural-networks-using-keras-on-   rescale/